# how to get sweave to center figures without centering code

Tags: r, latex, sweave

One way to get sweave to center figures is to include something like the following

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
[sweave chunk]
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, if you want to display the code to produce the visualization, the code comes out centered.  Does anyone know of a slick way to get the code to display left-justified while still making sure the figure is centered?  This is problematic if you set the size of the figure to say 3x3:

```
<<myplot, fig=TRUE, width=3, height=3>>=
    plot(rnorm(20), rnorm(20))        
@
```

I need to do this more than 100 times for a project I'm working on and would prefer not to create separate chunks for the plot and the code.

Comment: I get left justified text by default.

Comment: Are you perhaps using pgfSweave, this was a problem with earlier versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are after, but I like to keep the code I use to make the picture outside of the figure region, as I want the code in the text:

```
Blablabla if we run:
R CODE
We get the figure in Figure 1
```

You can do this by using `include=false` in the Sweave arguments and using the fact that if you make a picture in Sweave it calls the pdf `DOCUMENTNAME-PICTURENAME.pdf`. For example, in document `foo.Rnw`:

```
Blablabla if we run:
<<myplot,fig=true,include=false>>=
plot(1)
@
We get the plot in Figure \ref{myplot}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{foo-myplot}
\end{center}
\label{myplot}
\caption{This is my plot!}
\end{figure}
```

This should get your code left justified in the running text and the figure wherever LaTeX places it (if you want right there).

---

## Edit:

Running your example does get me left justified code at the same margin as normal text though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
<<myplot, fig=TRUE, width=3, height=3>>=
    plot(rnorm(20), rnorm(20))        
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `include=false` is nice; it gives you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: A side point though: make sure your `\label` is after `\caption`; otherwise the label will have the wrong thing in it.

Comment: You could actually use a code chunk containing `<<myplot>>` within your figure definition. I think that might be more robust

Comment: Wouldn't that run the code twice? i.e. costing time compiling?